# Converting a decimal number with non-repeating and repeating digits to an improper fraction

Tags: recreational-mathematics

What are the steps to convert $3.2\overline{901234567}$ to an improper fraction?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note $901234567/999999999=73/81=0.\overline{901234567}$

Comment: It's $533/162$.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! 533/162 is the answer I am looking for. I think I can figure out how you got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x = 3.2\overline{901234567}$$

$$10^9 x = 3290123456.7\overline{901234567}$$

$$(10^9 - 1)x = 329123453.5$$

so

$$x = \frac{3290123453.5}{999999999}$$

Comment: I think you left out a "9" digit in the bottom number

Comment: Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

$3.2\overline{901234567}=\dfrac{32}{10}+\dfrac{901234567}{9999999990}=\dfrac{32}{10}+\dfrac{73}{810}.$  Can you take it from here?

Comment: Your second fraction is off by a factor of $10$. The denominator should be $9999999990$.

Comment: Thank you, @kccu; I edited in the "$0$"

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write this repeating decimal using a infinite geometric series:
\begin{align*}
3.2\overline{901234567} &= 3.2+901234567(10^{-10}+10^{-19}+10^{-28}+\cdots)\\
&=3.2 + 901234567\cdot 10^{-10}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (10^{-9})^k\\
&=3.2 + 901234567\cdot \frac{1}{10^{10}}\frac{1}{1-10^{-9}}\\
&=\frac{32}{10}+\frac{901234567}{10^{10}-10}
\end{align*}
and now you can find a common denominator and add these fractions.